# What is the correct stackexchange site for questions about table lamps, toasters, hand mixers, and other small appliances?

Tags: discussion

I had a question about a table lamp pull chain mechanism, and saw that small appliances our out of the scope of the site. While my questin technically involves circuitry, it seems too mechanical/basic for Electrical Engineering.

Where should questions about small appliances go?

Comment: After talking to the EE people, I've started an Area51 proposal for a small appliance site:http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66039/small-appliances?referrer=M_IBOapHUgmWXYyF_kRbzQ2

Comment: Keep in mind the electronics/gadgets site failed due to lack of focus. It looks like you're covering a slightly different topic, but be careful not to repeat their mistake.

Comment: I agree with BMitch. I joined the proposal, but I am having trouble too. I just realized my question was out of scope of both EE & DIY as well, so I didn't post it.  The problem is, all kitchen tools (toasters, blenders, etc.) are actually acceptable to discuss for maintenance on the cooking.se site. I'm not sure where that leaves us.